# Drawing a line in MS Paint

Tags: c#, mouseevent

I'm new here and working on a project in C# where I use pixel coordinates to draw lines in MS Paint. Right now, I've automated mouse movements to open MS Paint in a panel in my Form, maximize inside the panel, select brushes, and select colors. I can make the cursor go to a point on the paint canvas, but when I use my left mouse click event, move the cursor to a new position, and then release the click to draw a line, the cursor just snaps to the coordinate where I raise the click and draws nothing. Here's my code (I'm sorry for this giant block, this is the first question I've ever asked and I want to provide as much context as possible):

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        // Function to simulate mouse events
        // Dll import to use character system
        [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);
        // Move the mouse
        const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;
        // Left click down
        const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
        // Left click up
        const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
        // Right click down
        const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008;
        // Right click up
        const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010;
        // Using absolute coordinates
        const int MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // Dll inport allows execution of external application inside program
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
        private void btnOpenPaint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Call OpenPaint Function
            OpenPaint();
            // Call CanvasSetup
            CanvasSetup();

            // Testing brush selects
            BrushMenu();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            BrushSelect();
            IndigoSelect();
            
            // This is me trying to draw a line, and where I'm having trouble
            Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(569, 469);
            // Click to start line
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            // Drag to make line
            Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(530, 450);        // The cursor just snaps here 
                                                          // after picking the color
            // Release mouse
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }


        // Function to Open MS Paint
        private void OpenPaint()
        {
            // Open MS Paint using file path
            Process proc = Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\mspaint.exe");
            // Opens outside the Panel for 1 second before the Form grabs it
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            proc.Refresh();
            // Form grabs paint and opens it internally
            SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, this.panelPaint.Handle);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            // Lock cursor interaction to inside the Form
            this.Capture = true;
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Clip = Bounds;
            // Move mouse to Paint taskbar
            Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(515, 85);
            // Double click to maximize Paint inside form
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        private void CanvasSetup()
        {
            // Move mouse to x:1840 y:935 to zoom in on canvas (already sized to resolution 315x207 px)
            Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(1840, 950);
            // Click '+' twice to zoom to 300%
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      Color Select Functions
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private void RedSelect()
        {
            // Mouse mouse to x: 980 y: 160 to select 'RED' Preset
            Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(980, 160);
            // Click 'RED'
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        private void OrangeSelect()
        {
            // Mouse mouse to x: 1000 y: 160 to select 'ORANGE' Preset
            Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(1000, 160);
            // Click 'ORANGE'
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        private void YellowSelect()
        {
            // Mouse mouse to x: 1020 y: 160 to select 'YELLOW' Preset
            Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(1020, 160);
            // Click 'YELLOW'
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        private void GreenSelect()
        {
            // Mouse mouse to x: 1040 y: 160 to select 'GREEN' Preset
            Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(1040, 160);
            // Click 'GREEN'
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        private void BlueSelect()
        {
            // Mouse mouse to x: 1065 y: 160 to select 'BLUE' Preset
            Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(1065, 160);
            // Click 'BLUE'
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        private void IndigoSelect()
        {
            // Mouse mouse to x: 1085 y: 160 to select 'INDIGO' Preset
            Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(1085, 160);
            // Click 'INDIGO'
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        private void VioletSelect()
        {
            // Mouse mouse to x: 1110 y: 160 to select 'VIOLET' Preset
            Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(1110, 160);
            // Click 'VIOLET'
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//       Brush Select Functions
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private void BrushMenu()
        {
            // Move mouse to x:485 y:215 to select menu
            Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(485, 210);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            // Click on brush menu
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        private void BrushSelect()
        {
            // Select 'Brush'
            Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(485, 240);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        private void AirbrushSelect()
        {
            // Select 'Airbrush'
            Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(600, 240);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0 ,0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        private void MarkerSelect()
        {
            // Select 'Marker'
            Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(560, 300);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        private void WatercolorSelect()
        {
            // Select 'Watercolor'
            Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(485, 330);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

I have looked into using a backgroundWorker or something, but since this is the most advanced project I've ever done I have no idea what I'm looking at when I see tutorials for how to use it, or how I can apply it to my code. I should note I've also tried moving the mouse 'x' units relative to current position, but it still doesn't work, it just snaps to the end coordinate.

Comment: I've never seen similar code tbh it's really original question, could the problem be because you are reinitializing the cursor, instead of just changing its position?

Comment: @funatparties It really is, I'm doing this for my senior design project! And I don't believe so, I just tried it without reinitializing it and it still snaps :( Thank you for the suggestion though!